# Where should I ask questions about research papers?

Tags: support, site-recommendation, list-questions

[My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14476782/voice-recognition-research-papers) about research papers was closed (which I have no problem with), but I got no hint on where it would be appropriate.

Where should the question be posted?

Comment: I'm afraid it's likely to be off topic on the entire network, as it's a question asking for a list.

Comment: @Pekka웃: It could be reworded to be narrow enough, see [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Even if it was edited to not ask for a list, it's still too broad/vague, it's asking for general information on the whole field, rather than with a specific question in mind.

Comment: @Servy: The topic is narrow enough, I'm not worried too much. You can ask "I have looked for good research papers on this and this subject. I used (linked to search engine) tool, looking for query1/query2/query3 but nothing showed up. What terms should I be looking for instead? Is there anything to find on the subject at all?" and that'd be fine and constructive.

Comment: @MartijnPieters "voice recognition" is not *that* narrow a field.  I can assure you there's *something* out there, so asking that would just result in a "Yes".  (Asking yes/no questions are almost always a bad idea; what you're *really* asking is almost always something else.)

Comment: @Servy: Sure, the question as asked on SO is too broad, but I still do think that you can make it into a Good Subjective question if you follow those guidelines I linked to.

Comment: @MartijnPieters And I think it's not possible, and the proposed change that you gave is certainly not appropriate.  It no longer not constructive, but it's still "too localized" and "not a real question", and the good subjective/bad subjective entry won't fix either of those problems.

Comment: @user1261166 Use your student ACM membership and search the library.

Comment: If you're having a lot of trouble finding articles on your own then speak with a librarian in your university's library.  It's their *job* to help other people find articles.

Comment: @Servy: and that would be a great answer to my reworded version....

Comment: @MartijnPieters That's not technically answering the question you asked.  It's not a search term, and it doesn't state whether or not there is any information out there.

Comment: Is a question on software engineering tools using voice recognition to broad as well? I mean there are questions about IDE's for Haskell (which is a "list question" as well, what's the difference?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to check the FAQ section of potential sites, always. If you look at the [Academia FAQ](https://academia.stackexchange.com/faq) for example, you'll see that your question would be off-topic there too (it's about *being* an academic, not about questions that academics could potentially answer).

The [Computer Science beta site](https://cs.stackexchange.com/faq) looks promising though:

> - Computer Science - Stack Exchange is for students, researchers and practitioners of computer science.

Since you are approaching a CS research problem, it would seem that your question *could very well* be on topic there.

The FAQ for that site is still under development it seems, as that community is coming to grips with what is and is not on-topic. Do look around at existing questions there, and when in doubt, ask on their [meta site](https://cs.meta.stackexchange.com/) if your question would be on-topic.

Also, please review the [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/) blog post to see if you can word your request in the most constructive form.

Answer (score 1):

It is not appropriate on any of the SE sites.  There are a number of problems with the post; some may be fixable, but some are too inherent to be fixed.

1. You're asking for a list of things (research papers).  That is not a proper format of questions for the Q/A style of this site, and so they are considered inappropriate.  (This is a fixable problem.)
2. The question is too localized.  It's specific to a moment in time.  New papers will be coming out, and either the list will need to be maintained, or (if you modify the question such that it's no longer asking for a list) the correct answers are very likely to need changing as a result of new papers coming out.  (This is fixable, but it will be harder to fix than #1.)
3. Your question is just too broad/vague.  You're asking for anything and everything about voice recognition in an academic environment.  That's a *lot* of information.  Books can be, and almost certainly are, written on the subject (which is basically what you're asking for).  That is one of the guidelines for determining that a question is too broad.  This really can't be fixed.  You need to be asking something specific about voice recognition, not just for general information about the whole field.

Comment: I would disagree with this answer. The question contains some specific details ("research-papers in the field of voice recognition", "usage of voice recognition as a development tool", "recent research in the Siri, Android 4.1+ era of smartphones"), the OP has already looked himself and can't find any, so it's likely there's a limited # of resources out there, and it's not too-localized as it would apply to anyone working with voice recognition as a development tool. It could probably use some tweaks, but I think it could be a decent SE question if we have a site where it would be on-topic.

Comment: @Rachel `"the OP has already looked himself and can't find any"` well, we don't really know that.  Anyway, he's looking for information about an entire *field* of research.  That's not a specific problem, it's *way* too broad.  As I said, he's looking to write a book on the subject; if it's a subject that a book could be written about then it's too broad.  As for too localized, it has two meanings.  It's not that it's specific to just the OP, it's that it's specific to a point in time.  Any answer will be obsolete in a year when there's new research.

Comment: Technically that kind of logic could apply to the entirety of StackOverflow, as technology is constantly evolving and changing. I think the *"specific moment in time"* referenced by the "too-localized" close reason is meant for things that only apply to a specific moment in time, such as a single event, and was not meant to apply to answers that would be good for years to come.

Comment: @Rachel Any answer to this question *wouldn't* be good for years to come though, that's the whole point.  A comprehensive resource on the research material in this field will be out of date as soon as new research is published, thus requiring the answer(s) be updated.  Additionally, most of SO is *not* too localized.  The answers to the questions asked don't change over time.  Many of the questions were questions people had 10, 20, 30+ years ago, and may likely have that long *from* now.